# Reading of DBname.system.indexes failed on Atlas cluster by mongobee after getting connected

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, jhipster, mongobee

I have a Jhipster Spring boot project. Recently  I shifted from *mlabs* standalone sandboxes to Atlas cluster sandbox M0 Free tier replica set. It even worked and I had made some database operations on it. But now for some reason then there is a read permission error

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongobee' defined in class path resource [DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 8000 and error message 'user is not allowed to do action [find] on [test.system.indexes]' on server ********-shard-00-01-mfwhq.mongodb.net:27017
```

You can see the full stack here https://pastebin.com/kaxcr7VS

I have searched high and low and all I could find is that M0 tier user doesn't have permissions to overwrite admin database which I am not doing.

Even now connection to Mlabs DB works fine but have this issue on Atlas DB M0 tier.

Mongo DB version : 3.4

Jars and It's version
name: 'mongobee', version: '0.10'
name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.4.2'

@Neil Lunn
The userId I am using to connect is that of admin's and the connection read and write works through shell or Robo3T(mongo client)

Comment: From the stack trace `'user is not allowed to do action [find] on [test.system.indexes]'` This means the user you are connecting to lacks the permission to do this on the current database. Either you're on the wrong database namespace for the user, or you assigned the wrong permissions to the user. The `readWrite` role should be a reasonable starter for most application usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After discussion with MongoDB support team, MongoDB 3.0 deprecates direct access to the `system.indexes` collection, which had previously been used to list all indexes in a database. Applications should use `db.<COLLECTION>.getIndexes()` instead.

From [MongoDB Atlas docs](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/#atlas-user-privileges) it can be seen that they may forbid calls to `system.` collections:

> Optionally, for the read and readWrite role, you can also specify a collection. If you do not specify a collection for read and readWrite, the role applies to all collections (excluding some system. collections) in the database.

From the stacktrace it's visible that [MongoBee](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee) is trying to make this call, so it's now the library issue and it should be updated.

**UPDATE**:
In order to fix an issue until [MongoBee](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee) has released new version:

1. Get the latest sources of [MongoBee](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee) `git clone git@github.com:mongobee/mongobee.git`, `cd mongobee`
2. Fetch pull request `git fetch origin pull/87/head:mongobee-atlas`
3. Checkout `git checkout mongobee-atlas`
4. Install MongoBee jar `mvn clean install`
5. Get compiled jar from `/target` folder or local `/.m2`
6. Use the jar as a dependency on your project

Comment: Even with the latest mongobee jar which is 0.13,  it is throwing the same error. How do we resolve this issue so that i can connect to Atlas cluster? any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: @Artist I've submitted a pull request to MongoBee library to fix this. I hope they'll merge it and release it soon. https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee/pull/87

Comment: That's is helpful. Do you recommend overriding the jar class to overcome this issue?

Comment: @Artist I would rather compile another `jar` with the pull request above, keep in repo and use it until the new library version is released.

Comment: @Artist I've added detailed steps on what to do, please check it out and accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Mongobee is no longer maintained, so that PR is still open. Projects that require production stability obviously cannot rely on a PR build, but a couple of years ago the mongobee project was forked to [mongock](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock), which actually addresses this exact problem. For those worried about the pains of moving from one dependency to another, I just did this in 5 mins with no issues

Answer (score 2):

Came across this issue this morning. Heres a quick and dirty monkey-patch for the problem:

```
package com.github.mongobee.dao;

import com.github.mongobee.changeset.ChangeEntry;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

import java.util.List;

import static com.github.mongobee.changeset.ChangeEntry.CHANGELOG_COLLECTION;

public class ChangeEntryIndexDao {

    public void createRequiredUniqueIndex(DBCollection collection) {
        collection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject()
                        .append(ChangeEntry.KEY_CHANGEID, 1)
                        .append(ChangeEntry.KEY_AUTHOR, 1),
                new BasicDBObject().append("unique", true));
    }

    public DBObject findRequiredChangeAndAuthorIndex(DB db) {
        DBCollection changelogCollection = db.getCollection(CHANGELOG_COLLECTION);
        List<DBObject> indexes = changelogCollection.getIndexInfo();
        if (indexes == null) return null;
        for (DBObject index : indexes) {
            BasicDBObject indexKeys = ((BasicDBObject) index.get("key"));
            if (indexKeys != null && (indexKeys.get(ChangeEntry.KEY_CHANGEID) != null && indexKeys.get(ChangeEntry.KEY_AUTHOR) != null)) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isUnique(DBObject index) {
        Object unique = index.get("unique");
        if (unique != null && unique instanceof Boolean) {
            return (Boolean) unique;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void dropIndex(DBCollection collection, DBObject index) {
        collection.dropIndex(index.get("name").toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I be able to use the above code, since it is a jar

Comment: If you put it in your own src/main/java folder under the matching package name com.gitgub.mongobee.dao it will override the jar ;) thus it should be consider a temporary solution! I’ll submit to mongobee for a future consideration

Comment: No worries, if this works for you please consider marking as answered. :)

Comment: this is a nice hack but overriding a jar class is not what I am looking for. If there are no more answers I will mark this as the answer

Comment: for further searchers, if get any error about loading this class twice (lib and classpath) you might need to exclude the class from mongobee that is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.github.mongobee.dao.ChangeEntryIndexDao.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.github.mongobee.dao.ChangeEntryDao.<init>(ChangeEntryDao.java:34)
    at com.github.mongobee.Mongobee.<init>(Mongobee.java:87)
    at com.xxx.proj.config.DatabaseConfiguration.mongobee(DatabaseConfiguration.java:62)
    at com.xxx.proj.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4ae465a5.CGLIB$mongobee$1(<generated>)
    at com.xxx.proj.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4ae465a5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f202afb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.xxx.proj.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4ae465a5.mongobee(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

jhipster 5 must be using a different version, because i get that when implementing the above code.  looks like its expecting a different version.

Answer (score 0):

This access to `system.indexes` is an [open issue](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee/issues/104) in [mongobee](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee).  The issue has been fixed in the project, but the project was abandoned before the fix was ever released.

Due to this project abandonment, two successor libraries have since been forked from mongobee which have fixed this issue: [Mongock](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock) and [mongobeeJ](https://github.com/cybuch/mongobeeJ).

Switching your application's dependency from the mongobee library to one of these successor libraries will allow you to run mongobee database migrations on Atlas.

To summarize these libraries:

- [Mongock](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock) - Forked from mongobee in 2018.  Actively maintained.  Has evolved significantly from the original, including built-in support for Spring, Spring Boot, and both versions 3 & 4 of the Mongo Java driver.
- [mongobeeJ](https://github.com/cybuch/mongobeeJ) - Forked from mongobee in 2018.  Five updated versions have been released.  Minimal evolution from the original mongobee.  Mongo Java Driver 4 support was implemented in August, 2020.  This project was deprecated in August, 2020, with a recommendation from its creators to use a library such as Mongock instead.