# How to include your github repository in gradle dependencies

Tags: github, gradle, jhipster, mongodb-atlas, mongobee

There are a lot of questions like this, but none seem to either work for me or answer my question directly.

I'm using Jhipster and MongoDB Atlas.  Jhipster uses a library called Mongobee has a method used in it that works for MongoDB, but not for MongoDB Atlas.  To boot, Mongobee seems not to be maintained anymore.

So I found someone's suggested PR that they sent to Mongobee for review, I took the code changes, forked Mongobee, and added these changes in my own repository.

I want to add this to my build.gradle dependencies, but keep coming up with "could not resolve all files for configuration 'compileClasspath'

> could not find com.github.myUserName:mongobee"

the URL to my repo:
https://github.com/myFakeUserName/mongobee

I've included jitpack.io in my

```
buildscript {
     repositories{
     mvn {url...}
    }
```

I'm hoping to get this forked and modified repo to be included as a gradle dependency in my java based application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a long while, I think I finally understand.

1) jitpack can't be used in buildscripts
I learned that here [What's the difference between buildscript and allprojects in build.gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158971/whats-the-difference-between-buildscript-and-allprojects-in-build-gradle)

2) afterwards run ./gradlew install

3) run ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies

4) crack a cold one ferda' bois'.

Now, I'm currently pointing to my local MongoDB instance.  I'm going to try to point it at Mongo Atlas (which is outside the scope of the immediate question), and if this is successful, I'll add my repo I forked from mongobee and modified with some other user's code(to whom, I'll give credit to) that solves this issue [Reading of DBname.system.indexes failed on Atlas cluster by mongobee after getting connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974594/reading-of-dbname-system-indexes-failed-on-atlas-cluster-by-mongobee-after-getti).